# adic periodic approximation of a dynamical system

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $P$ be [the Pascal adic transformation](http://www.univ-rouen.fr/LMRS/Persopage/Janvresse/Publi/pascal_adic_is_LB.pdf). The cutting and stacking construction of $P$ corresponds to a ``Pascal periodic approximation'' of $P$: a sequence $(P_n)$ of periodic automorphisms strongly converging to $P$ and for each $n$ the period of a point under $P_n$ is a binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}$. 
Does any ergodic automorphism admit such a "Pascal periodic approximation" ?